# Почему не отвечает бот в вк

Tags: python, vkontakte-api, бот

Нужно было переписать бота в вк. Начал писать код, ошибок не выдает, но в самом вк бот не отвечает. В чем я допустил ошибку?

````
import time
import random
 
token = "мой токен"
 
vk = vk_api.VkApi(token=token)
 
vk._auth_token()
 
while True:
    try:
        messages = vk.method("messages.getConversations", {"offset": 0, "count": 20, "filter": "unanswered"})
        if messages["count"] >= 1:
            id = messages["items"][0]["last_message"]["from_id"]
            body = messages["items"][0]["last_message"]["text"]
            if body.lower() == "Штирлиц проверка":
                vk.method("messages.send", {"peer_id": id, "message": "Все в полном порядке.", "random_id": random.randint(1, 2147483647)})
       
    except Exception as E:
        time.sleep(1)```
````

Comment: `body.lower() == "Штирлиц проверка":` XDXD. в ловертексте не МОЖЕТ БЫТЬ АППЕРКЕЙСА

Answer (score 0):

Во-первых тот код, который вы сюда прислали работать не будет, потому что вы не импортируете `vk_api`, но скорее всего вы забыли это прописать только здесь, раз вы говорите, что ошибок не возникает. Во-вторых метод `.lower()` возвращает строку в нижнем регистре. Скорее всего если вы замените `"Штирлиц проверка"` на `"штирлиц проверка"`, то всё заработает.